# Incremental and decremental count based on a date

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Name Start_date end_date
aaa  01/02/2017  05/03/2017
bbb  03/05/2017  07/07/2017
ccc  02/01/2017  10/09/2017
```

I want to write a query that calculates the number of people who exist in the DB in a certain month/year.

Answer:

```
Jan 2017  1
Feb 2017  2
Mar 2017  3
Apr 2017  3
May 2017  2 (one person - aaa ,ended in May 2017)
Jun 2017  2
Jul 2017  1 (bbb ended in July 2017)
```

How do I write a PSQL query to get the desired output?

Thanks.

Comment: Show your best attempt.

Comment: Are these fixed months you want to show? Or minimum `start_date` month (including) till maximum `end_date` month (excluding)? If the latter, why does your result end in July?

Comment: No this is a table that keeps updating with time. The result is just an example.

Comment: @koimoi, Can you pay attention to my answer?

Comment: I am looking for Postgres SQL query. I did try your query but does not work as I wanted it to work

Comment: What do you want?

Answer (score 0):

First, get the max and min dates in order to declare the dates range.

Second, with etc select all the month in the range.

Third, sum the number of the records in each dates.

Like:

```
declare @date date 
declare @toDate date 


select @date = min(Start_date),
       @toDate = max(end_date)
from table_name

;With dt As
 (
 Select @date As [TheDate]
 Union All
 Select DateAdd(month, 1, TheDate) From dt Where [TheDate] < @toDate
 ) 

 select month(dt.TheDate),
        year(dt.TheDate),
        sum(case when table_name.Name is not null then 1 else 0 end)
 from dt
 left join table_name   
    on table_name.Start_date >= dt.TheDate
    and table_name.end_date < dateadd(day,-1,dateAdd(month,1,dt.TheDate))
```